# How to Stop Scroll Deferring to Parent Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a parent container, which is set to `overflow: auto:` and a container inside of it with `overflow: auto`. When I am hovered over the child scroll container, I only want to scroll that container, never the parent container, and vice versa.

Currently though, when I scroll down my page, the parent scrolls until the child container, then begins to scroll the child container, then defers back to the parent container when the child has finished scrolling. Is there a way to prevent this?

Here is an example of what I have:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>Outter text</div>
    <div>Outter text</div>
    <div>Outter text</div>
    <div>Outter text</div>
    <div>Outter text</div>
    <div>Outter text</div>
    <div class="scroll-container">
        <ul>
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>Outter text</div>
    <div>Outter text</div>
    <div>Outter text</div>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
.parent {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.scroll-container {
    height: 35px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    color: red;
}
```

You will notice in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bC8Hz/) that as you scroll down to the `scroll-container` the scrolling will deffer first from the `parent` (which is expected since the mouse is hovered over the `scroll-container`), but then deffers back to the `parent` when it has reached the bottom (which is what I would like to prevent).

I'm not opposed to using jQuery/javascript, but I would like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks hacky but seems to fix it:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bC8Hz/4/)

```
(function () {
    var scrollTop;
    $('.scroll-container').attr('tabindex', -1).css('outline', 'none');
    $('.parent').on('scroll', function () {
        var $scrollContainer = $(this).find('.scroll-container');
        if ($scrollContainer.is(':focus, :hover')) {
            this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        }
    });
    $('.scroll-container').on('focus mouseenter', function () {
        scrollTop = $(this).closest('.parent').scrollTop();
    });
}());
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to do anything for me (in Chrome). If I scroll in the `scroll-container` and hit the bottom, the `parent-container` should not scroll since my mouse would still be hovered over the `scroll-container`

Comment: ya, because DIV hasn't the focus, you need to handle case of hover too, i'll update answer asap but i can not really test it because i don't have currently a mousewheel on my laptop mouse